# Non-reliable results from Expect when running a remote script

Tags: expect

Because my company insists on using sudo I now have to scrap my ssh system I've built for running remote commands.

I have a script that will connect to a server, sudo into the db2 inst owner account and then run a script (previously delivered into /tmp).  Maybe 1 in 10 times it will work (outputs 'Hello world' for my test).

Here is the ksh script on the remote server (/tmp/cwow/generic.ksh):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93
echo "Hello world"
```

[I've also tried adding sleep 5 and wait with mixed results but it doesn't solve the problem]

The expect script I'm running locally is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set spath /tmp/cwow/generic.ksh

set pass $env(MYEXPECTPASS)
set user $env(MYEXPECTUSER)

if { [llength $argv] != 2 } {
        send_user "USAGE: $argv0 host inst\n"
        exit
}
set host   [lindex $argv 0]
set inst   [lindex $argv 1]

set timeout 10
log_user 1
exp_internal 0

eval spawn /usr/bin/ssh -t $user@$host "sudo su - cwow"
expect {
        timeout { send_user "TimedOut"; exit }

        -glob "assword:" {
                send "$pass\r"
                expect {
                        -glob "assword:" {
                                send "$pass\r"
                                expect {
                                        -glob " " {
                                                send "/tmp/cwow/generic.ksh\r\n"
                                                expect {
                                                        -glob "world" {
                                                                send_user "Got it\r"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I should also note that I never get the 'Got it' message but I don't really need that to work, just curious why it doesn't.   What I need to work reliably is for the script to run and, most of the time, it doesn't appear to.

Any ideas for a weak expect user would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run your script with `expect -d` and see if your patterns are failing to match. Or `exp_internal 1` will turn on debugging.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` there.

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer, just a formatted comment)

You don't need to nest all the expect commands: if you expect a pattern with no action body, the script will continue to the next command. This is more readable, IMO:

```
expect {
    timeout { send_user "TimedOut"; exit }
    "assword:" 
}
send "$pass\r"
expect "assword:" 
send "$pass\r"
expect " "
send "/tmp/cwow/generic.ksh\r"
expect "world" 
send_user "Got it\n"
```

Note, you should `send` to the spawned process with `\r` as "hitting Enter". But `\n` is used for `send_user`.

Comment: Glenn, I took your commenting suggestion (MUCH CLEANER, thank you) and that will reliably work for my initial test program.   So, then I moved onto something a tad more complex:  I added a   touch /tmp/ABCD.out  before echo "Hello world".   The file never gets created but the expect does capture the "Hello world". I had thought, once I got the script to execute, I could then do anything. Is expect limited on what it will execute via a script?  I don't see how that could be.